# Problems with parser when trying to build Jack compiler using ply.yacc in python(nand2tetris project)

Tags: python, compiler-construction, yacc, ply, jack

As the code below, the lexer has no problem, and I also have no problem building parser. However, when I want to parse some easy text, and it the parser seems to call error message first. As the code and debug message below, after `while` enter the stack, the parser just call `p_error`. I guess the problem is some mistake when dealing with shift rule `p[0]=p[1]`, which I try to read the instruction written by David M. Beazley but didn't really understand. I am still not clear about how `p[0]=p[1]` is associated with the shift and reduce rule.
(After some fixing, I identified the main problem. The question is edited)

So the problem is:
1.What can I do to let my program properly parse?

2.What do `p[0]=p[1]` means? Does it means shift or reduce? Moreover, I saw some program wrote `p[0]=p[1]/p[2]` and I don't understand why `/` can be written like that. I consider it be something like `'/'` or be treated as token and just skip it.

Thanks!!

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
class JackLexer:
       ......

        ##########expression#################

    def p_error(self,p):
        print('Syntax error,p: ',p,'\n\n')
        if not p: return
    start='start'
    #delete expression, since there won't be a sentence only with expression
    def p_start(self,p):
        '''
        start : CLASS className '{' classVarDec subroutineDec '}'
              | statement
        '''
        print('start,p=:  ',p)
        if len(p)==2:
            p[0]=p[1]
        else:
            p[0]=[p[2],p[4],p[5]]
        print('p[0]is now after executing p[0]=p[1] in p_start:  ',p[0])
    def p_expression(self,p):
        '''
        expression : term 
                   | term opterm 
    
        '''
        print('expression,p=:',p)
        if len(p)==2:
            p[0]=p[1]
        else:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[2]
        
    #= (op term)*
    def p_opterm(self,p):
        '''
        opterm : op term
               | opterm opterm
               | empty
        
        ''' 
        if len(p)==3:
            p[0]=[p[1],p[2]]
        else:
            pass
        
    def p_term(self,p):
        '''
        term : integerConstant
             | StringConstant
             | keyword
             | varName
             | varName '[' expression ']'
             | subroutineCall
             | '(' expression ')'
             | unaryOp term
        
        '''
        if len(p)==2:
            p[0]=p[1]
        elif len(p)==3:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[2]
        elif len(p)==5:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[3]
        elif len(p)==4:
            p[0]=p[2]  
    
    def p_subroutineCall(self,p):
        '''
        subroutineCall : subroutineName '(' expressionList ')'
                       | classvarName '.' subroutineName '(' expressionList ')'
        
        '''
        if len(p)==5:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[3]
        else:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[3]+p[5]
    def p_classvarName(self,p):
        '''
        classvarName : className
                     | varName
        
        '''
            
        p[0]=p[1]
            
    def p_expressionList(self,p):
        '''
        expressionList : empty
                       | expression expression_comma
        '''
        if len(p)==3:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[2]
        else:
            pass
        
    def p_expression_comma(self,p):
        '''
        expression_comma : ',' expression
                         | expression_comma expression_comma
                         | empty
        '''
        if p[1]==',':
            p[0]=p[2]
        elif len(p)==3:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[2]
        else:
            pass
        
        
        
    def p_op(self,p):
        '''
        op : symbol
        '''
        p[0]=p[1]
    
    def p_unaryOp(self,p):
        '''
        unaryOp : '-' 
                | '~'
        '''
        p[0]=p[1]
    

    def p_empty(self,p):#??
        'empty :'
        pass
    
#######################################statement##############################
        
    def p_statement(self,p):
        '''
        statement : empty
                  | statement letStatement
                  | statement ifStatement
                  | statement whileStatement
                  | statement doStatement
                  | statement ReturnStatement
                  | letStatement
                  | ifStatement
                  | whileStatement
                  | doStatement
                  | ReturnStatement
        '''
        print('this is statement:',p)
        if p[1]=='':
            pass
        elif len(p)==3:
            p[0]=[p[1]]+p[2]
        else:
            p[0]=p[1]
    
    def p_letStatement(self,p):
        '''
        letStatement : LET varName letdesuka '=' expression ';'
        '''
        p[0]=[p[2]]+p[3]+p[5]
    def p_letdesuka(self,p):
        '''
        letdesuka : empty
                  | '[' expression ']'
        '''
        if len(p)==4:
            p[0]=p[2]
        else:
            pass
        
    def p_ifStatement(self,p):
        '''
        ifStatement : IF '(' expression ')' '{' statement '}' elsedesuka
        
        '''
        p[0]=[p[3]]+p[6]+p[8]
        
        
    def p_elsedesuka(self,p):
        '''
        elsedesuka : empty
                   | ELSE '{' statement '}'
        '''
        if len(p)==5:
            p[0]=p[3]
        else:
            pass
        
        
    def p_whileStatement(self,p):
        '''
        whileStatement : WHILE '(' expression ')' '{' statement '}'
        '''
        print('this is whileStatement,p: ',p)
        p[0]=['while']+'('+p[3]+')'+'{'+p[6]+'}'
        print(p[0])
        
    def p_doStatement(self,p):
        '''
        doStatement : DO subroutineCall ';'
        '''
        p[0]=p[2]
    def p_ReturnStatement(self,p):
        '''
        ReturnStatement : RETURN expressiondesuka
        '''
        p[0]=p[2]
    def p_expressiondesuka(self,p):
        '''
        expressiondesuka : empty
                         | expression
        '''
        if len(p)==2:
            p[0]=p[1]
        else:
            pass

    


    def buildParser(self):
        reserved = {'class':'CLASS',
                'constructor':'CONSTRUCTOR',
                'function':'FUNCTION',
                'method':'METHOD',
                'field':'FIELD',
                'static':'STATIC',
                'var':'VAR',
                'int':'INT',
                'char':'CHAR',
                'boolean':'BOOLEAN',
                'void':'VOID',
                'true':'TRUE',
                'false':'FALSE',
                'null':'NULL',
                'this':'THIS',
                'let':'LET',
                'do':'DO',
                'if' : 'IF', 
                'else' : 'ELSE',
                'while' : 'WHILE',
                'return':'RETURN'}
        tokens=['keyword','symbol','integerConstant','StringConstant','identifier']+ list(reserved.values())#list
        #start='statement'
        self.parser=yacc.yacc(module=self)
    
        
    def parse(self,data):
        s=self.parser.parse(data,debug=1)
```

In addition, trying to parse`while(x=2){x+3;}\nlet x=5`, I got debug message below, but I expected to get `keyword` shifted and reduced as `term`

```
PLY: PARSE DEBUG START

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(keyword,'while',2,0)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(keyword,'while',2,0)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,'(',2,5)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,'(',2,5)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',2,6)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',2,6)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,'=',2,7)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,'=',2,7)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(integerConstant,2,2,8)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(integerConstant,2,2,8)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,'){',2,9)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,'){',2,9)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',2,11)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',2,11)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,'+',2,12)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,'+',2,12)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(integerConstant,3,2,13)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(integerConstant,3,2,13)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,';}',2,14)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,';}',2,14)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(keyword,'let',3,17)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(keyword,'let',3,17)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',3,21)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(identifier,'x',3,21)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(symbol,'=',3,22)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(symbol,'=',3,22)

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(integerConstant,5,3,23)
ERROR: Error  : . LexToken(integerConstant,5,3,23)

State  : 0
Stack  : . $end
Action : Reduce rule [empty -> <empty>] with [] and goto state 4
Result : <NoneType @ 0x7ffa8b2ba880> (None)

State  : 4
Stack  : empty . $end
Action : Reduce rule [statement -> empty] with [None] and goto state 3
Result : <NoneType @ 0x7ffa8b2ba880> (None)

State  : 3
Stack  : statement . $end
Action : Reduce rule [start -> statement] with [None] and goto state 1
Result : <NoneType @ 0x7ffa8b2ba880> (None)

State  : 1
Stack  : start . $end
Done   : Returning <NoneType @ 0x7ffa8b2ba880> (None)
PLY: PARSE DEBUG END
```

Comment: You might try reading this simple introduction to context-free grammars: http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Handouts/. Note that it does not use the same syntax as Ply, but there's a simple correspondence. Also, it does not discuss reduction functions (which are what Ply functions are; there is no such thing as a shift function). But if you start with an understanding of grammars, it will be easier to read Beazley's documentation.

Comment: @rici TKS, I found the document helpful.
Sorry to ask more, parse tree parse from up to down, but the reduce rule seems to parse from tokens. Is my understanding correct?